# Does Haskell always know which 'return' to call?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am defining an instance of a monad as follows:

```
data Something = Something a

instance Monad Something where
    return a = Something a        --Wraps a in 'Something', correct?
    m >>= f = do
        var <- m
        return $ f var            --I want this to pass var to f, then wrap the result
                                  --back up in the 'Something' monad with the return I
                                  --Just defined
```

The questions are ->

1: Are there any glaring errors/misconceptions with what I am doing?

2: Will Haskell know to call the return I have defined above from `m >>= f`

3: If I for some reason define another function

```
f :: Something a -> Something b
f x = do
    var <- x
    return $ doMagicTo x
```

Will `return` call the return I defined in the monad instance and wrap x in `Something`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few big problems here.

First, a `Monad` instance must have [kind](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Kinds) `* -> *`.  That means they need at least one *type variable*, where your `Something` doesn't have any.  For comparison:

```
-- kind * -> *
Maybe
IO
Either String

-- kind *
Maybe Int
IO ()
Either String Double
```

See how each of `Maybe`, `IO`, and `Either String` need a type parameter before you can use them?  With `Something`, there's no place for the type parameter to fill in.  So you need to change your definition to:

```
data Something a = Something a
```

The second big problem is that the `>>=` in your Monad instance is wrong.  You generally can't use do-notation because that just calls the `Monad` functions `return` and `>>=`.  So you have to write it out without any monad functions, either do-notation or calling `>>=` or `return`.

```
instance Monad Something where
    return a = Something a        --Wraps a in 'Something'
    (Something m) >>= f = f m     --unwraps m and applies it to f
```

The definition of `>>=` is simpler than you expected.  Unwrapping `m` is easy because you just need to pattern-match on the `Something` constructor.  Also `f :: a -> m b`, so you don't need to worry about wrapping it up again, because `f` does that for you.

While there's no way to unwrap a monad *in general*, very many *specific* monads can be unwrapped.

Be aware that there's nothing syntactically wrong with using do-notation or `>>=` in the monad instance declaration.  The problem is that `>>=` is defined recursively so the program goes into an endless loop when you try to use it.

(N.B. `Something` as defined here is the [Identity monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html))

For your third question, yes the `return` function defined in the Monad instance is the one that will be called.  Type classes are dispatched by type, and as you've specified the type must be `Something b` the compiler will automatically use the Monad instance for `Something`.  (I think you meant the last line to be `doMagicTo var`).

Comment: This is great. All of these answers are so good. I feel compelled to remark that the Haskell community so far has been the most helpful and thorough of any I have encountered. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 8):

The main issue is that your definition of `>>=` is circular.

Haskell's do syntax is syntatic sugar for chains of `>>=` and `>>`, so your definition

```
m >>= f = do
    var <- m
    return $ f var
```

Desugars to

```
m >>= f = 
    m >>= \var -> 
    return $ f var
```

So you're defining `m >>= f` as `m >>= \...`, which is circular.

What you need to do with `>>=` is define how to extract a value from m to pass to `f`.  In addition, your `f` should return a monadic value, so using `return` is wrong here (this is closer to how you'd define `fmap`).

A definition of `>>=` for `Something` could be:

```
(Something a) >>= f = f a
```

This is the Identity Monad - there's a good deal written about it - it's a good starting point for understanding how monads work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Close. The `return` is redundant here and you need to add a type parameter to your `Something` type constructor. **Edit: This code is still wrong. The definition of `>>=` is circular. See the other answers for more information.**

   ```
   data Something a = Something a

   instance Monad Something where
       return a = Something a
       m >>= f = do
           var <- m
           f var
   ```
2. Since your definition for `>>=` is under the `instance Monad Something where`, `>>=`'s type is `Something a -> (a -> Something b) -> Something b`. So it can tell that `f var` has to be of type `Something b`. The term to google here is "type inference"
3. Yes. Again, this is type inference. If the compiler can't infer the type you want, it will tell you so. But usually it can.

Comment: See John L's solution: you can't use a do-block to define `>>=` like that, because how do you think the do-block gets de-sugared? (Also stated in rampion's solution.)

Comment: D'oh, good call. I must be thinking more like a Haskell programmer now, since I just took the OP's code, modified it until it type-checked and compiled, and said, "Yup, that must be right." :P Still, I think the OP's question was more or less "Does Haskell do type inference?" though they didn't ask it that way. And my main point was, yes, it does.